# how to export print result to excel using python (for loop)

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

Below is my code and need to generate the result into excel using xlsx writer module:

```
a=3
mylist = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'e': 5, 'f': 6}]
for i,l in zip(mylist,range(a)):
    print('\r')
    print('Result : {0}'.format(l))
    for key,value in i.items():
          print(key,':',value)
```

Comment: Please give more specification on how you would like your output

Comment: Result : 0
a : 1
b : 2

Result : 1
c : 3
d : 4

Result : 2
e : 5
f : 6

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a csv file?

Comment: You're really not asking a question here.  The implication from the tags is that you're expecting to use xlswriter but you need to provide your attempt at doing so, with any error or unexpected output you're producing before anyone can help.  The community won't tend to write code for you until you've had a go yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what extension you are talking about when you say Excel. But you can use .csv file to write to a file.

It should go something like this.

```
with open('out.csv','w') as f:
   for key,value in i.items():
       print(key,',',value)
```

or you can convert the dictionary into a Pandas Dataframe and export it as .xlsx file using to_excel() function built-in to Pandas. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html